# iPhone Crash Report

Tags: iphone, crash

My iPhone app is crashing for certain users in UK. I tried using UK timezone and their region format but couldn't reproduce the crash on my iPhone or emulator. Eventually got a crash report and I was able to symbolicate it. However, I have a hard time understanding the results. It appears thread 0 crashed in a system library. The only call from my app is main.m.

Thread 4 has something familiar. It was at:

```
My App 0x00004cca -[TocTableController parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] (TocTableController.m:1369)
```

Code is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
```

It crashed doing alloc/init? Out of memory, only in UK? Any one has idea what might be cause? Thanks in advance!

```
Date/Time:       2010-04-06 21:41:17.629 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.3 (7E18)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00090b2c __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00090b1a kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00090b0e raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000a7e34 abort + 36
4   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00066390 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 588
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00008898 _objc_terminate + 160
6   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00063a84 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00063afc std::terminate() + 16
8   libstdc++.6.dylib              0x00063c24 __cxa_throw + 100
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x00006e54 objc_exception_throw + 104
10  Foundation                     0x0000202a __NSThreadPerformPerform + 574
11  CoreFoundation                 0x000573a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1908
12  CoreFoundation                 0x00056c18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
13  GraphicsServices               0x000041c0 GSEventRunModal + 188
14  UIKit                          0x00003c28 -[UIApplication _run] + 552
15  UIKit                          0x00002228 UIApplicationMain + 960
16  My App                             0x00002414 main (main.m:14)
17  My App                             0x000023e4 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00001488 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00004064 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00057002 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 982
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00056c18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
4   WebCore                        0x000841d4 RunWebThread(void*) + 412
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002b780 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00001488 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00004064 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00057002 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 982
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00056c18 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 44
4   Foundation                     0x0005a998 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 172
5   Foundation                     0x00053ac6 -[NSThread main] + 42
6   Foundation                     0x00001d0e __NSThread__main__ + 852
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002b780 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x000262c0 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                 0x000207e2 __CFSocketManager + 342
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002b780 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x00015764 fegetenv + 0
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002a160 time + 8
2   libicucore.A.dylib             0x00009280 uprv_getUTCtime + 6
3   libicucore.A.dylib             0x0000a492 icu::Calendar::getNow() + 2
4   libicucore.A.dylib             0x0000a2a0 icu::GregorianCalendar::GregorianCalendar(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 86
5   libicucore.A.dylib             0x0000a242 icu::GregorianCalendar::GregorianCalendar(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 2
6   libicucore.A.dylib             0x000098ec icu::Calendar::createInstance(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 160
7   libicucore.A.dylib             0x00008762 icu::SimpleDateFormat::initializeCalendar(icu::TimeZone*, icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 28
8   libicucore.A.dylib             0x0000bd2c icu::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 82
9   libicucore.A.dylib             0x0000bcd2 icu::SimpleDateFormat::SimpleDateFormat(icu::Locale const&, UErrorCode&) + 2
10  libicucore.A.dylib             0x000084aa icu::DateFormat::create(icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::Locale const&) + 148
11  libicucore.A.dylib             0x0000840e icu::DateFormat::createDateTimeInstance(icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::DateFormat::EStyle, icu::Locale const&) + 14
12  libicucore.A.dylib             0x00008336 udat_open + 70
13  CoreFoundation                 0x0006c2e0 CFDateFormatterCreate + 252
14  Foundation                     0x00019fd2 -[NSDateFormatter _regenerateFormatter] + 198
15  Foundation                     0x00019ebe -[NSDateFormatter init] + 150
16  My App                             0x00004cca -[TocTableController parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] (TocTableController.m:1369)
17  Foundation                     0x000380e6 _endElementNs + 442
18  libxml2.2.dylib                0x00011d2c xmlParseXMLDecl + 1808
19  libxml2.2.dylib                0x0001ef08 xmlParseChunk + 3300
20  Foundation                     0x0003772a -[NSXMLParser parse] + 178
21  My App                             0x000055e2 -[TocTableController parseTocData:] (TocTableController.m:1120)
22  Foundation                     0x00053ac6 -[NSThread main] + 42
23  Foundation                     0x00001d0e __NSThread__main__ + 852
24  libSystem.B.dylib              0x0002b780 _pthread_body + 20

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x384e83cc
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x001d813c      r6: 0x2ffff2b8      r7: 0x2ffff2c8
    r8: 0x38385cac    r9: 0x0000000a     r10: 0x0002c528     r11: 0x0012be50
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2ffff2c8      lr: 0x33b3db21      pc: 0x33b3db2c
  cpsr: 0x00070010
```

Comment: can you post the corresponding code?

Comment: TocTableController.m:1369, code is (listed in the quesiton):

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

Answer (score 1):

The thread that crashed is running the main event loop. One of the things that happens there is that the autorelease pool is drained, so this might be a problem of an object being over-released.

If you could reproduce the problem, turning on NSZombieEnabled would be a good way to track down any over-release errors, but that's not something you can enable on a shipping application.

Comment: thanks. NSZombieEnabled=YES didn't find any problem. I have removed autorelease and used a different way of releasing memory. Hope this fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Believe me it is still the case. You have over-releasde object. Just use NSZombies to find an exact object that was managed improperly.